# ¿Porque las vistas importadas se convierten a tablas al hacerlo desde Local a Cpanel (PhpMyAdmin)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

cómo bien dice el título al importar mi base de datos completa desde PhpMyadmin en Local a mi servicio en Cpanel me da un error y se importaron como Tablas las Vistas.
Y no encuentro la forma de crearles manualmente a las mismas.

El error me decia algo como eso...

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias

Comment: El error dice que te faltan permisos...

Comment: si eso entiendo yo tambien pero no se como solucionarlo. por eso deje la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución y la dejo por si a alguien le sucede en en el futuro.
Cuando se exporta la Base de Datos completa las Vistas generan una linea como esta

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=**`root`@`localhost`** SQL SECURITY

y hay que reemplazar por el usuario que se obtiene en PhpMyAdmin haciendo clic en el icono de Home y luego en el apartado ***Servidor de base de datos*** está el usuario en uno de los items de este modo Usuario: **xxxxxxxxxxxx@localhost**